# How to write a jest test for opening of an URL in react native?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, automated-tests

I'm trying to write a test case for testing URL in my react native app this is my mock

```
import { Linking } from "react-native";

jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Linking/Linking', () => {
  return {
    openURL: jest.fn()
  }
})

Linking.openURL.mockImplementation(() => true)
```

and this is my test

```
test('open google url',async ()=>{
  expect(Linking.openURL()).toHaveBeenCalled('https://www.google.com/')
})
```

but I get this error what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name the mock function in a constant and then test if that function has been called.  Here's how you would set up:

```js
import * as ReactNative from "react-native";

const mockOpenURL = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(ReactNative, 'Linking').mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    openURL: mockOpenURL,
  }
});
```

and then you can test this way (my example uses react-testing-library, but you can use whatever).  Note you should use `toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)` instead of `toHaveBeenCalled(...)`

```js
test('open google url', async () => {
  // I assume you're rendering the screen here and pressing the button in your test
  // example code below
  const { getByTestId } = render(<ScreenToTest />);
  await act(async () => {
    await fireEvent.press(getByTestId('TestButton'));
  });
  expect(mockOpenURL.toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://www.google.com/'));
});
```